# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function with null values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've tried to remove the last part of a string. But its constantly failing to get the exact answer. However there's are NULLS and BLANKS. Here I tried to solve with two methods.. Please check the code

```
    SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(ISNULL(costing, 'no val'), 1 , CHARINDEX('-', costing+ ' ' ) -1) as temp,
    LEFT(ISNULL(costing, 'no val'), CHARINDEX('-', costing)-1)  as temp1 
    FROM xyz
```

I want to remove the last part of the string. ex. if i have 2010-2, the result is 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get everything before the hyphen:

```
select (case when costing like '%-%'
             then left(costing, charindex('-', costing) - 1
             else costing
        end)
```

Comment: Just to add to Gordon's answer.   CHARINDEX('-', costing)-1) was most likely generating a  -1 ... therefore causing the error.

Comment: thanks Gordon.. it worked like a charm. And thanks John for explaining. I was wondering what the problem was.